# Segmentation fault, MPI, when inserting into set

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, set, mpi

I am executing the following code inside the MPI "master" (rank 0). So no race conditions may occur.

```
    //Create a set which orders the elements according to their size.
    auto comp = [](const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b) -> bool
    {
        if (a.size() < b.size())
            return true;
        if (a.size() > b.size())
            return false;
        return a < b;
    };
    auto path = std::set <vector<int>, decltype(comp)> (comp);
    //Create an instance of Dijkstra's algorithm and execute it.
    Dijkstra<Graph, LengthMap> dijkstra_test(g,length);
    dijkstra_test.run(s);

    int size =0;
    //Print the path the algorithm found.
    for (Node v=t;v != s; v=dijkstra_test.predNode(v))
    {
        std::cout << g.id(v) << "<-";
        ++size;
    }
    cout << g.id(s) << endl;;

    //Fill the path set with all edges between source s and sink t. These will be used as tasks for the slaves.
    for (ListGraphBase::Arc v=dijkstra_test.predArc(t);s!=g.target(v); v=dijkstra_test.predArc(g.source(v)))
    {
        path.insert(vector<int>{g.id(v)});
    }
```

which works for small dataSets but for bigger one it throws a segmentation fault. The printing of the path is still executed correctly.

```
[Laptop:03801] *** Process received signal ***
[Laptop:03801] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[Laptop:03801] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[Laptop:03801] Failing at address: 0x7f5665be2ff8
[Laptop:03801] [ 0] /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x10f00)[0x7f5687345f00]
[Laptop:03801] [ 1] ./main[0x4102da]
[Laptop:03801] [ 2] ./main[0x409e31]
[Laptop:03801] [ 3] ./main[0x40b0b8]
[Laptop:03801] [ 4] /usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7f5686fb4741]
[Laptop:03801] [ 5] ./main[0x4094e9]
[Laptop:03801] *** End of error message ***
```

The whole program:

```
    #include <limits>
    #include <set>
    #include <map>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include "GraphElements.h"
    #include "Graph.h"
    #include "DijkstraShortestPathAlg.h"
    #include "YenTopKShortestPathsAlg.h"
    #include <sys/time.h>
    #include <mpi.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #include <lemon/concepts/digraph.h>
    #include <lemon/smart_graph.h>
    #include <lemon/list_graph.h>
    #include <lemon/lgf_reader.h>
    #include <lemon/dijkstra.h>
    #include <lemon/path.h>
    #include <lemon/bin_heap.h>

    using namespace lemon;

    //mpic++ main.cpp -o main Graph.cpp YenTopKShortestPathsAlg.cpp DijkstraShortestPathAlg.cpp -lemon
    //mpirun -np 4 ./main
    void run(int *argc, char ***argv  )
    {
        //Initiate the program run time counter.

        //Here starts the MPI block.
        MPI_Init(argc, argv);

        //Init the k for the number of paths
        int k = 5;
        //Init the rank of the MPI process
        int rank;
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,   &rank);
        //Init the number of processes.
        int nOSlaves;
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,   &nOSlaves);

        //Define the Parameter types of the lemon libraries.
        typedef lemon::ListGraph Graph;
        typedef Graph::EdgeIt EdgeIt;
        typedef Graph::Edge Edge;
        typedef Graph::NodeIt NodeIt;
        typedef Graph::Node Node;
        typedef Graph::EdgeMap<int> LengthMap;
        using lemon::INVALID;

        //Initialize the test graph.
        Graph g;

        for(int i = 1; i<= 1070376; i++)
        {
            g.addNode();
        }

        LengthMap length(g);

        string line;
        ifstream file ("output.gr");
        if (file.is_open())
        {
            string word;
            while (getline (file,line) )
            {
                std::string::size_type sz;
                file >> word;
                int node1 = stoi(word, &sz);
                file >> word;
                int node2 = stoi(word, &sz);
                file >> word;
                int distance = stoi(word, &sz);

                Edge edge = g.addEdge(g.nodeFromId(node1),g.nodeFromId(node2));
                length[edge] = distance;
            }
            file.close();
        }
        else cout << "Unable to open file";

        Node s = g.nodeFromId(10);
        Node t = g.nodeFromId(200);

        cout << "done adding graph, starting execution" << endl;

        //If the process is a coordinator.
        if(rank==0)
        {
            //Contains the shortest paths.
            multimap<int,vector<int>> shortestPaths;
            //Contains the already tried examples **Debug purpose**
            vector<vector<int>> removedPaths;
            //Contains the job of the currently running slaves at their index.
            vector<int> runningTasks[nOSlaves];

            //Create a set which orders the elements according to their size.
            auto comp = [](const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b) -> bool
            {
                if (a.size() < b.size())
                    return true;
                if (a.size() > b.size())
                    return false;
                return a < b;
            };
            auto path = std::set <vector<int>, decltype(comp)> (comp);
            //Create an instance of Dijkstra's algorithm and execute it.
            Dijkstra<Graph, LengthMap> dijkstra_test(g,length);
            dijkstra_test.run(s);

            //Fill the path set with all edges between source s and sink t. These will be used as tasks for the slaves.
            for (ListGraphBase::Arc v=dijkstra_test.predArc(t);s!=g.target(v); v=dijkstra_test.predArc(g.source(v)))
            {
                path.insert(vector<int>{g.id(v)});
            }

        MPI_Finalize();
    }




int main(int argc,  char    **argv)
{
    run(&argc,&argv);
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger (e.g. `gdb`) to see which line cause the segment fault

Comment: I used "comments" to debug and it seems that path.insert causes the crash.

Comment: The information you provide is incomplete. There is no way we can help you to debug that. You need to provide a [mcve]. In general you should use a debugger instead of "printf-debugging".

Comment: Added the complete example additionally.

Comment: The fine art is to make an example that is both complete and minimal. Minimal means to remove and simplify anything that is not needed to reproduce the issue. Complete means it compiles out of the box, e.g. includes are still missing.

Comment: This should do the job. I used the Florida distance graph list example and loaded the file in.

Comment: Any bigger example would do the job.

Comment: Considering that you don't do any MPI communication, can you reproduce the issue without MPI alltogether?

Comment: It prints:

Segmentation fault (core dumped)